# Error at connecting to MongoDB Atlas via VPC Peering from GCP Kubernetes Cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I am connecting a Nodejs app running on the GCP Kubernetes cluster. Before, it worked fine, when I enabled VPC Peering and I was using the connection string (Private). It is recommended on the Atlas dashboard:

> mongodb+srv://(username):(password)@<cluster_name>-pri.m6tkv.gcp.mongodb.net/<database_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority

I followed this tutorial to setup: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/security-vpc-peering/

I cannot understand since my app has been running for quite a while with this configuration. But one fine day, the app running on a pod in my GCP cluster is unable to connect.

Thats the error message:

```
Connected mongodb failed MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [<cluster_name>-00-00-pri.m6tkv.gcp.mongodb.net:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connection timed out  
at connectionFailureError (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:406:14)                                                                  
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:16)                                                                   
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)                                                                                                                                           
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)                                                                                                                                                
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:469:8)                                                                                                                                      
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)                                                                                                                                       
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7) {name: 'MongoNetworkError'                                                                                                                                                           }]                                                                                                                                                                                    at Pool.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/topologies/server.js:438:11)                                                                         
at Pool.emit (events.js:210:5)                                                                                                                                                     
at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:562:14                                                                                              
at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/pool.js:1009:9                                                                                              
at /app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:31:7                                                                                             
at callback (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:264:5)                                                                                 
at TLSSocket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/connection/connect.js:294:7)                                                                    
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:299:28)                                                                                                                                           
at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:210:5)                                                                                                                                                
at TLSSocket.Socket._onTimeout (net.js:469:8)                                                                                                                                      
at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)                                                                                                                                       
at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)
```

I switched back to the old connection (Standard), my app works again. The connection string:

> mongodb+srv://(username):(password)@<cluster_name>.m6tkv.gcp.mongodb.net/<database_name>?retryWrites=true&w=majority

So connection via VPC Peering is having some problem, I couldn't find any clue.

Comment: Is your cluster paired with a reserved IP? otherwise ips in GCP my change, and not be whitelisted anymore...

Comment: Is the peering in the same project as your cluster?

Comment: Yes, @guillaumeblaquiere, I setup peering in the project contains cluster on which my application is running

Comment: Same project and I assume in the same VPC, right? In addition, did you check your firewall rules?

Comment: I solved this problem by adding pod address range in my cluster to the IP whitelist on Atlas. Thank you for your time taking care of this, thank you very much !!!

Comment: I have this problem even after adding pod address range